# Change folder structure (of music collection) based on folder names (because Foobar2000 broke down)

Tags: shell-script, foobar2000

Dear superuser community, let me start by saying that I have very little programming experience, so apologies in advance in case my question might seem a little odd.

Recently I tried to restructure the folders of my music collection. Before, all albums were collected in one dedicated folder, so the base folder of the collection contained folders named something like

```
BASE\'<Artist> - [<year>] <album title>'
```

I wanted to change the collection's structure such that the files would be stored in folders along the "rule"

```
BASE\'<Artist>'\'[<year>] <album title>'
```

Foobar2000 succeeded in creating these new folders for most albums and moving the mp3's there. However, unfortunately the program crashed in the middle of the process, and the old folders still exist. These old folders still contain cover art etc.
I'm now left with, say, two folders per album: The artist's album subfolder with all mp3s, and the original folder with cover art.

Had it not crashed, Foobar2000 would have moved *all* content to the new subfolders and deleted the original ones. I'm now wondering if I can finish the job with something like a shell script (which I have never used before in my life)?

I guess the script would have to iterate over all folders in the `BASE` and

1. Test if the folder name has the structure `'<Artist> - [<year>] <album title>'` - say, by testing if it contains the middle part `' - '`
2. Test if the folder `'<Artist>'\'[<year>] <album title>'` exists and, if so, move all remaining content there
3. Delete the original folder `'<Artist> - [<year>] <album title>'`

Is this something a shell script could achieve? Any help or hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes a shell script can do this, however please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you! I apologize if I gave the impression that I wanted to abuse the community by expecting a ready-made solution. That was certainly not my intention. I'll admit that I haven't coded anything sofar - I have learned about shell scripts only yesterday. What I saw looked like implying a pretty steep learning curve for an inexperienced person like me, so I mainly wanted to make sure that a shell script can actually achieve a solution for my little problem before making the considerable time investment of starting to study shell scripts from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly the sort of thing you can do with a shell script. You've already done 90% of the work in exactly figuring out what your algorithm needs to do. Let me fill in some of the blanks.

[Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/%20Cygwin) will give you a bash scripting environment. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162821/bash-foreach-loop) suggests how to iterate through a list of things in bash. [grep](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html) will test the structure of the folder name and extract the parts of interest (e.g. artist name). [mkdir](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir) will create directories (you may want to investigate the `-p` option) and [rmdir](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rmdir) will remove them. [mv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) will actually move files from one directory to another.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the type of information I was hoping for. I'll definitely dig into it.

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel I have answered your question, please mark my answer as accepted. That rewards me with the delicious reputation points I crave and means your question will no longer show up in the list of unanswered questions where I found it.

Comment: I hadn't forgotten and had been hesitant to accept only because I haven't actually given your proposal a shot yet, but I'm very confident your answer has everything I need.